# How to include empty values using pivot dinamically in a query to create relationship between column and row

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a query who returns the next results

```
+-----------+--------+-------+
| idPeriodo | codigo | valor |
+-----------+--------+-------+
|     1     |   7    |  1000 |
|     1     |   8    |  1000 | 
|     1     |   9    |  1000 | 
|     2     |   7    |  1000 | 
|     2     |   8    |  1000 | 
|     3     |   7    |  1000 | 
|     3     |   9    |  1000 |  
+-----------+--------+-------+
```

I need to organize the query because I'm creating a text plain file with the results, so in the first row I need to put each "codigo" split by tab, something like this.

```
--This is the first row, is like a head
    7   8   9
```

Afther this, I need to put the column "valor" associated with its respective codigo and idPeriodo. The final result must be something like this:

```
    7       8       9
1   1000    1000    1000
2   1000    1000    
3   1000            1000
```

Now I have two queries, the first one is to obtain the first row(head with codigo values) and second one I'm doing a query to obtain all values from column "valor" grouped by idPeriodo.
These are my queries looks like.

```
-------Query to return head(codigo values)---------------
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(conjunto.codigo, central.confterm_id) as codigo_central 
FROM   mantenimiento_central_termica mantenimiento 
JOIN   configuracion_central_termica central 
ON     central.confterm_id = mantenimiento.confterm_id 
JOIN   conjunto_centrales conjunto
ON     central.id_conjuntocentral = conjunto.id

-------Query to return valor grouped by idPeriodo---------------
SELECT id_periodo , 
       valor_mantenimiento = string_agg(valor_mantenimiento, CHAR(9))
       WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY codigo_central)
FROM(
SELECT CONCAT(conjunto.codigo, central.confterm_id) as codigo_central, 
       per_id                          AS id_periodo , 
       mantenimcentraltermica_potencia AS valor_mantenimiento 
FROM   mantenimiento_central_termica mantenimiento 
JOIN   configuracion_central_termica central 
ON     central.confterm_id = mantenimiento.confterm_id 
JOIN   conjunto_centrales conjunto
ON     central.id_conjuntocentral = conjunto.id
WHERE  cas_id = 2) main_thermal
GROUP BY id_periodo
```

The problem I have is the second query returns only the values from column valor who is not null and when I'm going to split the first query with the second one I obtain something like this:

```
    7       8       9
1   1000    1000    1000
2   1000    1000    
3   1000    2000    --The error is here, because the 2000 value must be in the third column, with the 9(codigo) value.
```

I need the query put a blank space when find a null valor in a relation between codigo and idPeriodo.

How Can i do that ?

Comment: Essentially you need to "pivot" the table.

Comment: This doesn't look like a `STRING_AGG` problem, but more like a pivot/cross tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "easiest" way to pivot data, in SQL Server and in my opinion, is by using a Cross Tab. Based on the sample data we have, this would mean that your query would look something like this:

```
SELECT idPeriodo,
       MAX(CASE codigo WHEN 7 THEN valor END) AS [7],
       MAX(CASE codigo WHEN 8 THEN valor END) AS [8],
       MAX(CASE codigo WHEN 9 THEN valor END) AS [9]
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY idPeriodo;
```

Seems you need a dynamic pivot, which would be like the below:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT idPeriodo,' + @CRLF +
           STUFF((SELECT N',' + @CRLF +
                         N'       MAX(CASE codigo WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(codigo,'''') + N' THEN valor END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(codigo)
                  FROM dbo.YourTable
                  GROUP BY codigo
                  ORDER BY codigo
                  FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,3,N'') + @CRLF +
          N'FROM dbo.YourTable' + @CRLF +
          N'GROUP BY idPeriodo;';
--PRINT @SQL; --Your debugging friend.
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: Thanks to answer. The problem is "codigo" is not a static table. So, codigo could has 1000 values. it is a dinamic table who always is growing up. so I can't use a CASE clause in my select query. I have executed the query using your suggestion and that works, but just for the example I provided. I need to do this with all codigos in the table

Comment: So you need a dynamic Pivot? That information should have been in your question, but still, we can work with that. Give me 10.

Comment: Yes, I think I need a pivot, but I'm not an expert in SQL, so I didn't know about pivot, I'm reading in this moment about that. I gave you 10 ;)

Comment: I meant give me 10 minutes, @Allanh , that was 5 ;). Anyway, new answer done.

Comment: You're a master. Really, I don't know what to say. Thanks so much. The more I learn the more ignorant I feel. Thanks so much. Just a simple correction of typographical error. You wrote twice MAX CASE(

Comment: Oops, fixed @Allanh .

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using `pivot` :

```
select idPeriodo, [7],[8],[9] 
  from tab
 pivot
 (
  max(valor) for codigo in ([7],[8],[9])
 ) t;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8a6520d5c12f8ef10122963fc1fb29ee)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks Barbaros, but how can I build a pivot dinamically? I mean, 7,8 and 9 are values who are not static, I could have 1000 values or just one, it depends for the table who save this values.

Comment: you're welcome. There's a famous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10404455/5841306) of Taryn for dynamic pivot @Allanh .